# How set float precision for 'echo' in php more 12 digits without number_format()?

Tags: php, precision

PHP code:

```
$val1 = 32;
$val2 = 0.00012207031255;
$res = $val1 - $val2;
echo "echo: ".$res."\n";
echo "json: ".json_encode($res)."\n";
echo "form: ".number_format($res, 14);
```

Output:

```
echo: 31.999877929687
json: 31.99987792968745
form: 31.99987792968745
```

How to display 14 decimal places in echo without `number_format()`

I tried setting `precision=14` in `php.ini` but nothing changed

Comment: "_but nothing changed_" You _did_ restart your server after making changes, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a Global solution for the whole project without changing each line of code you can set `ini_set('precision', 14)` in the bootstrap file or set the same value in php.ini.

To format a single value you can use `sprintf()` function with 14 decimal characters format.

**Code :**

```
$val1 = 32;
$val2 = 0.00012207031255;
$res = $val1 - $val2;
echo sprintf("echo: %.14f\n", $res);
echo "json: ".json_encode($res)."\n";
echo "form: ".number_format($res, 14);
```

**Result :**

```
echo: 31.99987792968745
json: 31.99987792968745
form: 31.99987792968745
```

Comment: Yes. it's good solution but i working with big project, where a lot of "echo" in foreign code. And i can't edit it

Comment: update the code for adding a global solution.

Comment: Great, just what I need

Answer (score 1):

You can use [sprintf()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

```
$val1 = 32;
$val2 = 0.00012207031255;
$res = $val1 - $val2;
echo "echo: ".rtrim(sprintf("%.14f", $res), "0")."\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use mathematical php module functions:

```
php > $a = 32;

php > $b = 0.00012207031255;

php > echo bcsub($a, $b, 14);
31.99987792968745
```

More detail is [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php)